# I am getting a strike through on the content in drupal

Tags: drupal

[image]

[image]

I am getting this strike through error over the content in my drupal website 
please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error was with my html , i had a typo  instead of  and that was creating the bad html.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a rogue CSS rule on your text.

```
.myclass {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

If you right-click on your page and hit inspect element you should be able to figure out where that is coming from. Or you could search for this in the css of your theme and alter it there.